# How do I add sqlite3 to my project

Tags: c++, sqlite

How do I statically link the sqlite3 libary to my C++ program?
I am using the G++ compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Unix/Linux you'll have to make sure the library (e.g. libsqlite3.a) is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then you add "-lsqlite3 -static" to the g++ option.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on Linux and using the GNU `ld` linker:

`g++ <your-code> -Wl,--Bstatic -lsqlite3`

Of course, if `libsqlite3.a` isn't in your library path, you have to pass the directory it's in to the compiler as an additional `-L` flag.

If you don't have a static version (I don't on my system), you either have to check if you can get one or if you'll have to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux system I recommend using pkg-config.
Running pkg-config --cflags --libs --static sqlite3 should give you the compiler and linker flags you need.

Comment: Didn't know about this one, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to www.sqlite.org and download the latest version's amalgamation tarball. Include their source files to your project (make file, whatever) and forget about it. It's embedded anyway, they compile in a jiffy, if you put into your version control repo, you know what version you're using in what version of your application and you can forget about linking options. Just remember that their source files are C and not C++.